# problem with making nested statement in a single query

Tags: sqlite

I have a large table like this:

| id | name | grade | date-time | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | 2 | 2020-12-17 14:20:10 | 1022 |
| 2 | bar | 2 | 2020-12-17 14:20:18 | 872 |
| 3 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 4 | ... | ... | ... | ... |

i want to select the records after putting some criteria:

1- first of all sorting the records based on descending date-time: 
`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date-time DESC -> output1`.

2- get output1 and check 
`if (grade = x and code = y):`
`SELECT * FROM (output1) WHERE grade=x AND code=y -> output2`.

3- sort the records of output2 based on descending id: 
`SELECT * FROM (output2) ORDER BY id DESC -> output3`.

4- select records that have id between a and b: 
`SELECT * FROM (output3) WHERE id > a AND id < b`;

how can I put these tasks in a single query?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. A SQL query is a set-operation, not a series of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

As this is one table, it would require one query to select the desired rows in the desired order. There doesn't seem to be any point to ordering the rows before applying the WHERE conditions. One WHERE clause can be used to select the rows with the desired conditions (easy because they are all AND conditions). One ORDER BY clause can be used to present the rows in the desired order.